# Install Eclipse plugin - "no repository found at jar"

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install a plugin I wrote.

Using Eclipse Add/Remove Software, I am using the "Add Archive" and choosing the zip file I just distributed.

(Plugin written and tested in eclipse-RPC and I try to install on MyEclipse)

During the installation I get: "no repository found at jar" error.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Please post the contents of the file, e.g. it's file and folder structure.

It seems that the ZIP file is not in the format of an **Archived Update Site**.
The ZIP file should contain the following items in the root:

```
plugins/
features/
site.xml
artifacts.xml
contents.xml
```

Comment: hey, my site.xml isn't being created, why's that??